# gitlab clone from python got error Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: python-3.x, cron, gitlab

I write a py script to clone the repos at once as follow.

```
import os
from gitlab import Gitlab

# Register a connection to a gitlab instance, using its URL and a user private token
gl = Gitlab('gitlab_ip', private_token='My token',  ssl_verify=False)
groupsToSkip = ['my group']

# gl.auth() # Connect to get the current user

gitBasePathRelative = "bkup/gitlab/temp"
clone = "git clone "

for p in gl.projects.list(all=True):
    if p.name in groupsToSkip:

        print(p)
        pathToFolder1 = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), gitBasePathRelative, p.namespace.name)
        if not os.path.exists(pathToFolder1):
            os.makedirs(pathToFolder1)

        pathToFolder = os.path.join(pathToFolder1, p.name)
        if not os.path.exists(pathToFolder):
            # Repo.clone_from(p.ssh_url_to_repo, pathToFolder)

            # git.Git(pathToFolder).clone(p.ssh_url_to_repo)

            os.chdir(pathToFolder1)
            os.system(clone + p.ssh_url_to_repo)
```

it is working in my terminal. but when I run it in crontab, I got the following error.

Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

How can I?